# Regular Expression for reverse Firstname Lastname pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have been stuck at this problem for sometime now; I have to capture the last first name and title from the following sample string

1.LASTNAME/FIRSTNAME MIDDLENAME1 MIDDLENAME2 MIDDLENAME3 .. MIDDLENAMEn TITLE

FIRSTNAME and MIDDLENAME may not be present
now TITLE can be one of these values MR / MISS / MRS / MSTR / MASTER only; or it could be blank like FIRSTNAME and MIDDLENAME

```
(?<number>\d+)\.(?<surname>[a-z\s]*)\/((?<firstname>[a-z]+\s{0,1}))*(?<title>mrs|mr|miss|mstr|master){0,1}
```

In PHP preg_match does not do the trick as the firstname group doesnt capture mutiple values

how can i do this through regex only??

Comment: Hint: `{0,1}` is the same as `?`.

Comment: i know ... but that helps me think better!!

Comment: Trying to force people's names into a rigid scheme usually doesn't work so well ...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not missing something…

```
$str = '1.LASTNAME/FIRSTNAME MIDDLENAME1 MIDDLENAME2 MIDDLENAME3 TITLE';
preg_match('/^(?<number>\d+)\.\s*(?<surname>[^\s\/]+)\s*\/?\s*(?<name>[^\s]+)?(.*?)(?<title>[^\s]+)$/',$str,$matches);

echo "\$str: $str\n\n";
echo "number: {$matches['number']}\n";
echo "title: {$matches['title']}\n";
echo "name: {$matches['name']}\n";
echo "surname: {$matches['surname']}\n";
```